# Spring Security Registration- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null

Tags: html, spring-security, null, thymeleaf, registration

I'm currently working on a Spring Project and I completed  a tutorial to allow new users to be registered and stored in a database.

My issue is that the tutorial used a Json request/Postman to add the new user but I am trying to adapt it to allow users to register themselves using details they input into a Thymeleaf HTML registration form.

The following Controller class successfully registers a user using Json/Postman requests:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/registration")
 @RestController
 @AllArgsConstructor

public class  RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;


    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }


@GetMapping(path = "confirm")
public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
    return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
}
```

However my below attempt to make it use user imputed values from a Thymeleaf HTML form returns the following on submission of the form:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor

public class  RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
    
  
    @GetMapping("/api/v1/registration/new")
    public String ShowRegisterationForm (Model model) {
        RegistrationRequest request = new RegistrationRequest();
        model.addAttribute("request", request);
        return "registration";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/registration")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("request")RegistrationRequest request) {
            registrationService.register(request);  
            return "redirect:/dish";
            }
```

See my registrationRequest class below:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor


public class RegistrationRequest {
    private  String restaurantName;
    private  String email;
    private  String password;

    public RegistrationRequest(String restaurantName, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    
}
```

See my HTML registration form below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Registration and
                    Login Module</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Create HTML registration form -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <!-- success message -->
                <div th:if="${param.success}">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">You've successfully registered
                        to our awesome app!</div>
                </div>

                <h1>Registration</h1>

                <form th:action="@{/api/v1/registration}" method="post"
                    th:object="${request}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="restaurantName"> Restaurant
                            Name </label> <input id="restaurantName" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{restaurantName}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label> <input
                            id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required
                            autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label> <input
                            id="password" class="form-control" type="password"
                            th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                        <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login
                                here</a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See my RegistrationService class below:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private final EmailSender emailSender;

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {

        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());
        if (!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email not valid");
        }

        String token = appUserService.signUpUser(
                new AppUser(request.getRestaurantName(), request.getEmail(), request.getPassword(), AppUserRole.USER));

        String link = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/registration/confirm?token=" + token;

        emailSender.send(request.getEmail(), buildEmail(request.getRestaurantName(), link));

        return token;
    }

    @Transactional
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService.getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("token not found"));

        if (confirmationToken.getComfirmedAt() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email already confirmed");
        }

        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();

        if (expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("token expired");
        }

        confirmationTokenService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        appUserService.enableAppUser(confirmationToken.getAppUser().getEmail());
        return "confirmed";
    }
```

See my AppUser  class below

```
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    // Auto generate primary key
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
    @Column(name = "Rest_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Rest_Name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "Rest_Phone_Number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "Rest_Password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "Rest_Email_Address")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AppUserRole appUserRole;
    private Boolean locked = false;
    // don't enable user until email verification
    private Boolean enabled = false;

    public AppUser(String restname, String email, String pass, AppUserRole app) {
        this.restaurantName = restname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = pass;
        this.appUserRole = app;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    
    //need reference to restaurant info but one to one relationship 
    //already defined by openingHour object in opening hour table
    
    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "appUser"
            )
    private OpeningHour opening;
}
```

Please see the Stacktrace of the error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
rawPassword cannot be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:107)
    at com.bron.demoJPA.appuser.AppUserService.signUpUser(AppUserService.java:51)
    at com.bron.demoJPA.registration.RegistrationService.register(RegistrationService.java:36)
    at com.bron.demoJPA.registration.RegistrationService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12afc64f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.bron.demoJPA.registration.RegistrationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67a444d4.register(<generated>)
    at com.bron.demoJPA.registration.RegistrationController.registration(RegistrationController.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've spent hours on this but can't work it out. Maybe it is something to do with @RestController vs @Controller?

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the exception? Can you add the code of `AppUser` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug your controller method for `/api/v1/registration` you will notice that all of the fields on `RegistrationRequest` are `null` because there are no setters.

The object is constructed using the no args constructor and then the fields are set using the setters. Since the setters don't exist, all fields, including the password are `null`.

You can fix this by simply adding setters to `RegistrationRequest`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You don't know the hours I've spent looking at this! I think because the Postman/Json requests were working I didn't think to question the RegistrationRequest class, but I guess they add the request directly and don't need setters....

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This exactly solves my problem.